# "When what you really should do is ***"

Tags: grammar

I was wondering whether the following sentence is grammatically correct:

> It's remarkable how many ideas for interesting programming projects pop up in your head when what you really should do is **to study**!

Is *to study* used correctly? Or should it just be *study*?

Comment: I would use study.

Comment: . . . when what you *really* should be doing, is studying.

Comment: Related, though sort of the opposite: [“All you have to do is read” vs. “All you have to do is to read”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104546/all-you-have-to-do-is-read-vs-all-you-have-to-do-is-to-read)

Comment: @KristinaLopez That sounds good to me!

Comment: This question does not identify a specific point of difficulty with "to study". Questions which just ask "is this right or wrong" are proofreading requests, off topic.

Comment: Certainly it does, in the usual ELU.SE hamhanded way: is it sposta be _when what you really should do is study_ (with **no** _to_)? Or is it sposta be _when what you really should do is to study_ (**with** _to_)? And of course the answer is that it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @MετάEd, actually, the OP *does* ask about use of "to study" or "study" which isn't strictly proofreading, to me, anyway.

Comment: I don't see why anyone would assume there might be any difference between asking about *All you have to do is [to] **read*** and asking about *What you really should do is [to] **study***. So I think this ***is*** a duplicate of [“All you have to do is read” vs. “All you have to do is to read”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104546/)

Comment: @KristinaLopez The OP just asks which one is correct in the sentence, which is proofreading/writing advice. "Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified." The OP needs to express the source of concern: what specific doubts does the OP have about using one or the other, and what research has the OP done before asking for expert help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, but normally we omit "to" from an infinitive when it isn't serving as a noun phrase. The effect of putting the "to" back in is to make the statement sound very strong. It works quite well if you imagine the speaker raising his/her voice towards the end of the sentence and really punching out those last few words.