# Omitting the last "to" in "All {I need to / have to / must} do is (to?) do something"

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives, copular-verbs, bare-infinitive

I remember I learned a structure like the one that this post’s title mentions:

> All I {need to do | have to do | must do} is do something.

But is it correct to use "to do something"  after the "is" —  as compared with just plain "do something" without the "to"?

Or to be more specific, which of the following sentences in each pair is correct, or are both version correct?  The second one in each case adds "to" to the formula:

---

### Pair #1:

> 1. All I **must do is prepare** myself for the test.
> 2. All I **must do is *to* prepare** myself for the test.

---

### Pair #2:

> 1. What we **should do is teach** children how to think.
> 2. What we **should do is *to* teach** children how to think.

---

As far as I could remember, both forms should be fine.  But it seems that all the materials, texts, and articles I've read so far use the first form only.

Furthermore, I'd really appreciate it if you could show me some references, like webpages or some book, where I could find more information about this point.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3578 and [tag:bare-infinitive].

Comment: I really think that saying something like *“All I want to do is eat supper and go to sleep”* without the extra *to* is the most normal way that is said.

Comment: @tchrist: Entirely agree. It is, though, easily confused with *All I need now is to eat and sleep*, where *to* is not optional.

Comment: @TimLymington, sure it’s optional—removing it just changes the word class of ‘eat’ and ‘sleep’ from infinitives to pure nouns: “All I need now is eat and sleep”. (Okay, okay, ‘eat’ as a singular noun is perhaps not quite idiomatic …)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct. The first is the one I'd use and is the idiomatic one. The second sounds fine and there's nothing wrong with it, but only less idiomatic and that's why you don't see it in your written materials. In addition to that, the *to* in there is unnecessary and doesn't really add anything to the overall meaning of the sentence. Most grammar books should cover these topics, but personally I am not aware of one. On top of that, that part of your question seems a bit off topic on this site. Good luck with your grammar.

**Edit**

Here's a link to [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=should%20do%20is%20go,should%20do%20is%20to%20go,must%20do%20is%20go,must%20do%20is%20to%20go&year_start=1840&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=) that supports my assumption. Thanks to Peter for providing that.

Comment: Asking for references is off-topic here? I don't think so. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Here is support for your answer through [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=should+do+is+go%2Cshould+do+is+to+go%2Cmust+do+is+go%2Cmust+do+is+to+go&year_start=1840&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=). The version with the infinitive is the traditional construction, but over the last century it has been  replaced by the version without the infinitive. Fascinating!

Comment: @PeterShor Not references. He is asking for tutorials and books related to the study of grammar that covers this topic. Don't you think that's off topic?

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you for the link. I'll embed that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT After searching the site (why didn't I do this *before* writing?)
I found this answer to a similar question [All you have to do is read” vs. “All you have to do is to read”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/104593/44619) Which explains far better than I could ever do.

Here are a few online references which deal with the aspect of choosing between the bare infinitive (or base verb) and the full infinitive form (with *to*).

[My English pages](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-infinitive.php)

> **The bare infinitive**
>
> The bare infinitive is used as the main verb after the dummy auxiliary verb do, or most modal auxiliary verbs (such as will, can, or should..)
> Examples:
>
> I do know him
>
> I do like you.
>
> I can do it .

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive#Uses_of_the_infinitive)
Uses of the infinitive

> - As complements of other verbs. **The bare infinitive is used as
>   complement of the dummy auxiliary do**, most modal auxiliary verbs,
>   verbs of perception such as see, watch and hear (after a direct
>   object), and the verbs of permission or causation make, bid, let, and
>   have (also after a direct object). The to-infinitive is used after
>   many intransitive verbs such as want, aim, like, fail, etc., and as a
>   second complement after a direct object in the case of verbs such as
>   want, convince, aim, etc.
> - As a noun phrase, expressing its action or state in an abstract,
>   general way, used as the subject of a clause or as a predicative
>   expression: "To err is human"; "To know me is to love me". The bare
>   infinitive can be used in such sentences as "**What you should do is
>   make a list.**" A common construction with the to-infinitive involves a
>   dummy pronoun subject (it), with the infinitive phrase placed after
>   the predicate: "It was nice to meet you."

[Grammaring](http://www.grammaring.com/do-does-did-bare-infinitive)
"Do/does/did bare + infinitive" and "Infinitive [after modals]"(http://www.grammaring.com/the-infinitive-after-modals)

> Modal verbs
>
> Modal verbs (can, could, may, might, will, shall, would, should and
> must) are followed by a bare infinitive:
>
> ```
> I could hear the dog barking outside.
> You must be joking.
> He may have caught the train.
> You should have told me earlier.
> ```

In the case of:

- All I *must do is **to** prepare* myself for the test.
- What we *should do is **to** teach* children how to think.

The to-infinitive is used after *ought*, *used*, ***be*** and *have* which are called semi-modal verbs or modal auxiliary verbs. They are different from other modal verbs in that they are followed by the to-infinitive.

Examples

- *She* **ought** *to go home now.*

  *You **ought** to see a dentist*

  *He **used to** go down the pub a lot.*

  *She never **used to** drink wine at lunchtime*

  *We **have to** wear a uniform for work* (meaning of "external" obligation)

  *I'm sorry, I **have to** leave now.* (or "... *I must leave now*")

**be + infinitive** see the Wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_tense#English)

(often used to talk about a future arrangement or plan and for giving orders)

- *The President **is to visit** Great Britain in the Autumn.*

  *John **is to leave** tonight*

  *They **are to marry** next week.*

  *You **are to do** your homework*

  *Tell her **she's** not **to be** back later than midnight.*

EDIT #2 / Conclusion

Both the bare infinitive and the to-infinitive forms are acceptable, with the first structure sounding more natural and clearly used more frequently in everyday speech. I was intrigued by the question and wanted to know *why* the to-infinite structure could be used. I believe in the sentence

> All I *must do is **to** prepare* myself for the test

The *is + to prepare* expresses an arrangement or plan sometime in the future. This is grammatical, albeit very formal. It nevertheless sounds better than the equivalent:

> All I **have to do** is *to prepare* myself for the test

The repetition of the particle, to, in *have to* and *to prepare* sounds awkward to my ears, but interestingly the meaning remains virtually unchanged. *Have to* and *must* both express a form of obligation, although grammar books will tend to emphasize that *have to* is more commonly preferred when speaking about the law, rules, and regulations; whereas *must* expresses personal choice (I must see that film) or necessity.