# To use ‘to’ or not is the question ;)

Tags: do-support, bare-infinitive, verb-stacking

I believe the grammatically correct way is to omit the *to* before the verb (*find* in this case). Can someone confirm?

> What you have to do instead is find a way to redefine the problem ...

I ask this because I have also seen constructions like

> What you have to do instead is *to* find a way to redefine the problem ...

Are both correct?

Comment: Check "what you have to do is find" against "what you have to do is to find" using Google searches. Make sure that most of the early results are distinct and relevant. What do the results suggest?

Comment: Neither of your sentences contains even a single preposition.  Both contain none at all.

Comment: This point seem to have already been answered on ELU. Please check previous posts.

Comment: @tchrist What is the difference? And, is the "both ... none" a novel construction?

Comment: @Noah answered this beautifully in http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122277/omitting-the-last-to-in-all-i-need-to-have-to-must-do-is-to-do-somet and also, I got to know this wonderful tool from Google -- Google Ngram Viewer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can confirm that it’s grammatical to omit *to*.  In fact, I find the sentence mildly degraded when *to* is included.

Answer (score 1):

"To" can be used as an adverb. In this case, "to" is perfectly fine. You can also remove "to" without any problems.