# "I've got more to do than wait" or "I've got more to do than **to** wait"?

Tags: grammar, comparatives, bare-infinitive

I did some reading in other places online about using the bare infinitive after the word "than," and while in a lot of cases it seems correct, I'm having a hard time telling whether it's correct in this particular case. Are both of the following valid?

- 1.) "I've got more to do than wait."
- 2.) "I've got more to do than **to** wait."

I also noticed that it seems like the first one sounds better if there's something after the word "wait":

- 3.) "I've got more to do than wait *around for you*."

Is this any more valid than the first sentence with the bare infinitive after "than"?

Comment: Related: [“All you have to do is read” vs. “All you have to do is to read”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104546/)

Comment: @Reg Close enough to be a duplicate? I think so.

Comment: That example doesn't have the word "than" involved, which I think is a big enough difference for this to not be considered a duplicate (though it is clearly a similar discussion).

Comment: "I've got better things to do (rather) than sit and wait all day"