# How to use "The first thing I did was"?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I'm unable to figure out if the following sentence is correct:

"After I watched the movie, the first thing I did was shutdown the laptop and go outside"

Is this grammatically correct? Or should it be "..went outside".
Please help.

Answer (score 10):

The only thing wrong with the original sentence is that *shutdown* is a noun. You are looking for *shut down*, the verb.

The rest of the sentence is fine. Your confusion stems from the fact that *shut* is both the bare infinitive and the simple-past form of *to shut*. With a different verb in its place for which that is not the case, it likely wouldn't have arisen.

Constructions of the form "[what X] [did was|do is|does is]" take the infinitive. Here are the actual usage stats from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and the [British National Corpus (BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/):

| form | COCA | BNC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| did was [infinitive] | 726 | 138 |
| did was [simple-past form] | <10 | 0 |

As a side note, don't listen to people who insist (even on this page) that the infinitive must not be a bare one. Quite the opposite is in fact true:

| form | COCA | BNC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| did was [bare infinitive] | 476 | 47 |
| did was [to-infinitive] | 250 | 91 |

That is, both forms are fine, and the to-infinitive is preferred by a factor of less than 2 in British English, while for American English, the preference is actually *flipped*. So, as is often the case with language, it doesn't hurt to know your audience.

For further information and even more stats, see e.g. [“All you have to do is read” vs. “All you have to do is to read”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/104593/300) and the many related questions linked from there.

Comment: Nice info there. Does that come specifically from clefts? If so which types of cleft did you include? I'm asking because I'm interested in the status of *to* in those constructions - well actually altogether.

Answer (score 4):

"The first thing I did was **to** shut down the laptop and go outside" is right. You are not supposed to use *went* if the sentence is already in the past (I *did*).

Comment: Yes - but equally valid: *"The first thing I did was **I** shut down the laptop and [I] **went** outside"*.

Comment: I use *went* in sentences that are in the past all the time. In fact I never use it in sentences that are not. That part definitely needs rewording.

Comment: By the way, COCA has three cites for "did was went". And while that message may have been brought to you by a devil's advocate, the following one certainly is not: it also has almost 500 cites for "did was [bare infinitive]", but only 250 for "did was [to-infinitive]". So this answer goes against actual usage. I guess at this point I might as well post an answer myself...

Comment: +1 Quite. I assume it's because the original is two coordinated verb phrases, whereas your example's two coordinated finite clauses. Your example's deceptive in its resemblance to the OP's original though, because *shut* in yours is the past simple form, *shut* in theirs is the infinitive. This is cuz of the irregular verb *shut*.  *The first thing I did was **eat** an apple and went outside* versus *The first thing I did was I **ate** an apple and ...* shows up the difference a bit more. :)

Comment: Putting the "to" in there is very formal.  Leaving it out is perfectly common usage.   It is really gramatically _incorrect_ to leave it out?

Comment: RegDwight, I hope you don't mean you'd say "the thing I did was went outside".

Comment: @GreenAsJade : I'd have to disagree.  There are plenty of COCA attestations with  
 the marked infinitive in that construction, in everyday register.  We can probably find *First thing I did was t' cook me up that raccoon*  somewhere if we look long enough.

Comment: @RegDwigнt  A 2 to 1 ratio is not enough to conclude that something "goes against actual usage."

Comment: @Tim I dunno, t' is very different to to, in terms of formality.   Note that in your example sentence the speaker left out "The", which also indicates informality.  Maybe "formality" is not quite the right description of the effect of putting "to" into the sentence, but it certainly feels different - more thoughtful if not more formal.   Is it gramatically incorrect to leave it out? (I rarely include it :) )

Comment: @GreenAsJade I find the *the first thing I did was...* construction  awkward to begin with, but it sounds even more awkward with the marked infinitive.  Formality often feels awkward, but I think there's awkwardness at both ends of the informal-formal spectrum.

Answer (score 3):

You can take that like a bit of brain logic :)

*The first thing I DID*

gets you to a PAST reference

*was TO shut the computer down ...*

the Infinitive keeps you **the same** level or logical plane (you name it) as the main PAST you have in DID.

You can 'stay there'

*and GO out ...*

Comment: Right. It doesn't have anything to do with tense, though -- the conjoined infinitive clause _to shut down the laptop and (to) go outside_ simply gets its repeated infinitive marker _to_ deleted by [conjunction reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299). The problem with tense came up because _shut_ is the same form in infinitive and past tense, whereas _go_ and _went_ use completely different roots (the technical term for this is Suppletion). So if _shut_ is parsed as a past tense form, then the question is what the parallel verb should be. But it's a false trail.

Comment: @JohnLawler - I was hoping you'd comment. I was about to answer the question and was stopped short, not having a good way to explain it.

Comment: @JohnLawler -- I say the Infinitive, not a past form. I do not understand your idea for parsing; how would you expect your explanation to work for a learner?

Comment: No, you explained the level of clause involved correctly, @Teresa, but this isn't so much about what it means (logic) as it is about how the syntax works. There are two infinitives joined with a conjunction -- _to shut_ and _to go_, but neither has its complementizer _to_ present in the sentence. It can be there; deletion is optional -- _the first thing I did was **to** shutdown the laptop and go_ and  _the first thing I did was **to** shutdown the laptop and **to** go_ are both grammatical, and both mean the same thing. In a cleft sentence with Active _do_, one uses infinitives.

Comment: @John Lawler, To me, it is always about what it means, and syntax does not go any other way. You have the present, past or future reference and the Infinitive 'economizes' on the verb form -- you don't need to repeat the marker. Here, a past form in the main clause allows the bare infinitive.