# Which sentence is correct and why? with 'to' or without 'to'

Tags: grammar, orthography, sentence-patterns

> 1. *All I can do is **to** tell her not to go out during the weekend*.
> 2. *All I can do is tell her not to go out during the weekend*.

Comment: The infinitival marker "to" is optional in this kind of clause, i.e. one where the subject NP contains "do" in a relative clause.

Comment: @BillJ I'm not sure if I've understood your message.  Are both sentences correct?

Comment: Yes, both sentences are fine. The "to" is optional here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“All you have to do is read” vs. “All you have to do is to read”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104546/all-you-have-to-do-is-read-vs-all-you-have-to-do-is-to-read)

Comment: @Laurel The link you provided is useless. It doesn't even mention the fact that this is a predicative complement in a reversible specifying construction, nor that the bare infinitival is restricted to cases where the subject contains "do" in a relative clause, and the "to" can optionally be added.

Answer (score 1):

> *All I can do is* [*tell her not to go out during the weekend*].

The bracketed element is a predicative complement of "be" in a reversible specifying construction, where the complement can be a *to*- infinitival or a bare infinitival (or a gerund participial)

Note, though, that the bare infinitival is restricted to cases where the subject noun phrase contains "do" in a relative clause, as it does here.

"To" can optionally be added here (*All I can do is to tell* ...)